# Accept email id as an action parameter to a controller in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

How can I make my controller action to accept email as a param.

These are the routes I have

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "infoNewsletterSignup",
                url: "info/SubscribeToNewsLetter/{email}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Info", action = "SubscribeToNewsLetter", email =UrlParameter.Optional});

            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Info", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

This is my controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public string SubscribeToNewsLetter(string email)
{
   return "Thanks!\n\nYou have successfully subscribed for our newsletter.";
}
```

And this is my view

```
<td>
<input type="text" class="text-bx-foot" value="" id='newsLetterEmail' name='newsLetterEmail'></td>
<td>
<input name="Go" type="button" class="go-btn" value="Go" id="btnSubscribeToNewsLetters"></td>

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnSubscribeToNewsLetters").click(subscribeToNewsLetters);
});

function subscribeToNewsLetters() {
var objInputEmail = $("#newsLetterEmail");
if (objInputEmail != null) {
    var id = objInputEmail.val();
    if (id != null) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Info/SubscribeToNewsLetter/' + id,
            //data: $('#form').serialize(),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            traditional: true,
            success: subscribed,
            error: errorInSubscribing
        });
    }
}
}

function subscribed(data, textStatus, xhr) {
alert(data);
}

function errorInSubscribing(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert(textStatus);
}
```

**If I am entering values just like normal text the action is being invoked. But if I am trying to enter values like 'myname@test.co.uk' I am getting '404 not found' error.**

Comment: why not send it in json format?

Comment: tried JSon.Stringfy(id)....but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about sending it like this :

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Info/SubscribeToNewsLetter',
                data: {"email" : Id },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                traditional: true,
                success: subscribed,
                error: errorInSubscribing
            });
```

EDIT :

try surrounding it inside double quotation:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Info/SubscribeToNewsLetter',
                 data: '{"email" : "' + Id + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                traditional: true,
                success: subscribed,
                error: errorInSubscribing
            });
```

Comment: Getting internal server error. nvalid JSON primitive: email.
\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.\r\n\r\n

\r\n\r\n Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: email.

Comment: change the email to something else.maybe it is a special keyword.

Comment: Still getting the same exception even after changing emai to emailId

Comment: i found another solution from here http://encosia.com/asmx-scriptservice-mistake-invalid-json-primitive/ and updated the code.check.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Behnam. This time I am getting differenet eroor. The view 'SubscribeToNewsLetter' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. Here actually I am trying to invoike action 'SubscribeToNewsLetter' under 'Info' controller.